# Idiomatic React for Blueprintjs Toast component

Tags: reactjs, idioms, blueprintjs

The Blueprint UI library provides a [Toaster](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#components.toaster) component that displays a notice for a user's action. From the documentation, it's used by first calling

`const MyToaster = Toaster.create({options})`, followed by

`MyToaster.show({message: 'some message'})`.

I'm having trouble fitting the `show` method into React's lifecycle - how do I create a reusable toaster component that will display different messages on different button clicks? If it helps, I am using MobX as a data store.

Comment: I have the same problem. I solved partially putting Mytoaster.show in the render method with a if control. I use Redux, and when my error props change I render Mytoaster.show, else null. Now my problem is fire an action on dismiss..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Toaster` is a funny one in this regard because it doesn't care about your React lifecycle. It's meant to be used imperatively to fire off toasts immediately in response to events.

Simply call `toaster.show()` in the relevant event handler (whether it's a DOM click or a Redux action).

See how we do it in the example itself: [toastExample.tsx](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/master/packages/core/examples/toastExample.tsx#L85-L89)

Answer (score 0):

My solution with Redux (and `redux-actions`)...

**Action:**

`export const setToaster = createAction('SET_TOASTER');`

**Reducer:**

```
const initialState = {
  toaster: {
    message: ''
  }
};

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_TOASTER':
      return {
        ...state, 
        toaster: { ...state.toaster, ...action.payload }
      };
  };
}
```

**Toaster Component:**

```
// not showing imports here...

class MyToaster extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // set default toaster props here like intent, position, etc.
      // or pass them in as props from redux state
      message: '',
      show: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.toaster = Toaster.create(this.state);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // if we receive a new message prop 
    // and the toaster isn't visible then show it
    if (nextProps.message && !this.state.show) {
      this.setState({ show: true });
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.show) {
      this.showToaster();
    }
  }

  resetToaster = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });

    // call redux action to set message to empty
    this.props.setToaster({ message: '' });
  }

  showToaster = () => {
    const options = { ...this.state, ...this.props };

    if (this.toaster) {
      this.resetToaster();
      this.toaster.show(options);
    }
  }

  render() {
    // this component never renders anything
    return null;
  }
}
```

**App Component:**

Or whatever your root level component is...

```
const App = (props) =>
  <div>
    <MyToaster {...props.toaster} setToaster={props.actions.setToaster} />
  </div>
```

**Some Other Component:**

Where you need to invoke the toaster...

```
class MyOtherComponent extends Component {
  handleSomething = () => {
    // We need to show a toaster!
    this.props.actions.setToaster({
      message: 'Hello World!'
    });
  }

  render() { ... }
}
```

Comment: I have some questions about this as I'm trying to implement this in quite a large code base. Any chance you have a few minutes? Can give you my email @logik

Comment: @joshuaaron Sure thing, what's your question?

Comment: could you possibly shoot me an email at josh_reynolds_@hotmail.com, questions with screenshots will help.